# Android Calculator, How to display ridiculously large numbers in exponential form

Tags: android, calculator

I am making a calculator for Android and i just realized that if a user's calculation results in a number so large that it should only be displayed exponentially.... how would i do this

does anyone know an algorithm to get the root of any large number?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just make it so that if the number is over certain amount of digits, you turn it into an exponent.

Comment: I did not realize there was a method for converting to exponents, thanks i will look it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found on performing my calculation, where i realized the android OS automatically displays large numbers in exponential form.